# Randomised list in Python using a for loop?

Tags: python

So i have to make a list print in a randomised order every time using python.

I have this:

```
import random
print("Below is a random implementation of some words:")

list = ["programming", "technology", "numeracy", "web dev"]
random.shuffle(list)  #<---- could use a for loop
print(*list)

input(" ")

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit")
```

This is fine. However I was asked to try and do this with a for loop but I cant even think about how to do this? Any idea?

Comment: Do you want to replace `random.shuffle` by a for-loop, or do you just want to print out 100 shuffled lists?

Comment: Ideally i would need to replace it with a for loop

Answer (score 0):

A trivial algorithm would be to make a for-loop, that switches 2 random elements in the list over and over.

This isn't really efficient (you need a huge number of switches), and it is biased. That means, that some permutations are more likely to appear than others.

A great algorithm is the **Fisher-Yates shuffle**. Take a look at the wiki-page: [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)
The Fischer-Yates shuffle does almost the same thing, it switches random elements with a for loop, but it a way, that has linear run-time and guaranties to be unbiased.

Answer (score 0):

That's how `shuffle` is implemented in Python ([link to source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/random.py)):

```
def shuffle(self, x, random=None):
    """Shuffle list x in place, and return None.

    Optional argument random is a 0-argument function returning a
    random float in [0.0, 1.0); if it is the default None, the
    standard random.random will be used.

    """

    if random is None:
        randbelow = self._randbelow
        for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
            # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
            j = randbelow(i+1)
            x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
    else:
        _int = int
        for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
            # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
            j = _int(random() * (i+1))
            x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```